# How do I retrieve data automatically on app start up through parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, database-backups, oncreate

Currently I can only retrieve data when I click the refresh button.

How do I make it retrieve the data from parse automatically each time I start the app or even each time I switch between pages?
Thanks.

Relevant code:

```java
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

  String eventTxt;
  EditText seteditTxt;
  ParseObject Events = new ParseObject("Events");

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    seteditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seteditTxt);
    updatelocalData();
    updateData();
}

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    seteditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seteditTxt);
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
      updatelocalData();
      updateData();
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_example) {
      eventTxt = seteditTxt.getText().toString();
      Events.put("EventName", eventTxt);
      Events.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
            // Saved successfully.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            // The save failed.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
      Events.pinInBackground();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  public void updateData() {
    ParseQuery < ParseObject > query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
    query.getInBackground("d51GM3syxp", new GetCallback < ParseObject > () {
      public void done(ParseObject Events, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          String Txt = Events.getString("EventName");
          seteditTxt.setText(Txt);
        } else {
          // something went wrong
          System.out.print("Error in parse retrieving");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void updatelocalData() {
    ParseQuery < ParseObject > query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.getInBackground("d51GM3syxp", new GetCallback < ParseObject > () {
      public void done(ParseObject Events, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          String Txt = Events.getString("EventName");
          seteditTxt.setText(Txt);
        } else {
          // something went wrong
          System.out.print("Error in locally retrieving");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I add:

```java
seteditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seteditTxt); 
updatelocalData(); 
updateData();
```

in my onCreate() it gives me an error in the first updatelocalData() method at seteditTxt saying: 
*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference –*

activity_my.xml file :

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"  android:background="@drawable/background">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.mycompany.e_planner.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The fragment xml file:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.mycompany.e_planner.Calendar1"
android:background="#7dffe7f5">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/seteditTxt"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#7dfff6ec"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:text=" " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have a base activity and write ur logic, So when ever u navigate between activities it loads the content from parse

Comment: Thanks. Base activity as in? The data is displayed on fragments  - this is the Main Activity. @HarshaVardhan

Comment: Fine. still you can create base fragment and onstart of fragment call the method of base activity

Comment: when I place it in onCreate it gives me an error in my update method saying attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference –

Comment: add activity_my.xml file

Comment: seteditTxt is not there in activity_my.xml, obviously when u try to add some text setText it throws exception

Comment: its in the fragment file - I'm using a navigation drawer fragment.
The code works if I use the refresh button on action bar to retrieve data - but I want it to automatically show the data.

I'm adding the fragment xml file where seteditTxt is retrieved from

Comment: seteditTxt will be the part of fragment view but not activity view. So the variable seteditTxt is null. When onCreate of activty is created, fragment oncreate is not yet called. So the variable value will be null itself.

Comment: assign the id in oncreate of activity is wrong, if the id belongs to fragment

Comment: Oh alright, so putting it in onCreate of main activity makes setEdiTxt null because fragment activity is not called yet? How could I resolve this issue then?

Comment: Thanks solved it - used it in the fragment file instead

Answer (score 0):

Just move the relevant methods, I suppose these:

```
  updatelocalData();
  updateData();
```

to Activity's `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, or `onResume()` depending on your needs.
If you do it in `onCreate()` make sure all the UI elements including `EditText seteditTxt` the methods rely on have been initialized.

Comment: when I add:  
        seteditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seteditTxt);
        updatelocalData();
        updateData();

in my onCreate() it gives me an error in the first updatelocalData() method at seteditTxt saying:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you post the code of onCreate ? You can also try calling the methods in onStart

Comment: Well basically you cannot find an EditText of a fragment from your activity. The menu works because when you click refresh, fragment layout is already attached to activity's. But it's wrong and dangerous. You should use listeners or EventBus/Otto to communicate between Activity and Fragment.

Comment: oh okay, thanks. I'm not sure how listeners would work. 

I tried retrieve in my fragment activity - but for some reason it cannot resolve 'findbyView' in findViewById(R.id.seteditTxt) part.

Comment: Solved it! I retrieved from the fragment file instead. thanks